# How can I deny all the public access to my azure cache for redis?

Tags: database, azure, azure-caching

I want to deny all the public traffic from accessing my cache redis, I could not find any proper solution, any help will be appriciated.

Answer (score 1):

As the question is about denying the public traffic, I would suggest you to do it via Azure built in policy.

[Azure Cache for Redis should disable public network access](https://portal.azure.com/#blade/Microsoft_Azure_Policy/PolicyDetailBlade/definitionId/%2Fproviders%2FMicrosoft.Authorization%2FpolicyDefinitions%2F470baccb-7e51-4549-8b1a-3e5be069f663) denies the public endpoint access. Assign this at the appropriate level in your tenant.

Here is the snippet from above policy definition::

```
"policyRule": {
  "if": {
    "allOf": [
      {
        "field": "type",
        "equals": "Microsoft.Cache/Redis"
      },
      {
        "field": "Microsoft.Cache/Redis/publicNetworkAccess",
        "notEquals": "Disabled"
      }
    ]
  },
  "then": {
    "effect": "[parameters('effect')]"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of [`Private Endpoint`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/private-link/private-endpoint-overview) to do that. Instructions specific to securing an Azure Cache for Redis so that it is not accessible publicly can be found here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-cache-for-redis/cache-private-link.